# Why doesn't my MSO profile have a link to my SO account

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, meta

The other metas (MSF, MSU) have a link to the parent site's profile, why don't we have one here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSO is a different Meta site.  It's Meta Central for the whole system, and specifically Meta for SO.  It was the first Meta, and has always required it's own profile.

Comment: I would be nice if there was a link to the main profile (even if we had to add it ourselves)

Comment: @NullUserException - An account of meta doesn't require you have an account on SO :)  Also even if you do, it may not be associated, have the same username, etc...you're actually a different user here

Comment: But isn't it possible to link the information, so you don't have to repeat it on your profile page?

Comment: @user3305035, yes, you can have one profile that works across all the Stack Exchange sites.  Click on the `network profile` link in your profile here.