# Link between SO on meta.SO account in user profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add links between user's SO and MSO profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116237/add-links-between-users-so-and-mso-profile)

Currently if you want to get to the SO user of a certain meta.SO account, one needs to go through the Accounts tab, which means several extra clicks. That's pretty annoying IMO.

Other meta sites have a direct link:

[image]

Please add that link on SO and meta.SO if there is exactly one linked account on the other side.

Comment: You are aware that Meta and SO do not share the same Parent/Meta-Relationship the new SE sites have?

Comment: While the relationship between SO and MSO is different to other sites and their meta sites, I think this would be a useful link.

Comment: @Bobby Yes I know. But if there is a single linked account(the common case for people having a meta account at all), it should still be possible to display that link. It might cost too much performance, but that's not something I can judge.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - It implies they have the same relationship...they don't.  The user on the other side may not exist, and what's shown in the other direction?  Plenty of people with users here are exclusively from *other* sites on the network, not SO...it simply isn't the same, or worth the additional confusion.

Comment: @Nick If there is no SO user, don't show the link on meta.SO, and if there is no meta.SO user, don't show the link on SO. I don't think this would cause confusion, it's just a shortcut that's not applicable in every case.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - It does cause confusion, you're looking at it from a SO user's point of view...not from the view of this being a central site for the network from someone who knows nothing about SO.  I've already discussed this, just not awake enough to find the duplicate at the moment...this has been requested and discussed before.

Comment: The link should be labeled "Stackoverflow profile"(not "parent user", which would indeed be confusing) and should only be show on accounts that have an associated SO account. In the worst case it's a useless link, in the best case is saves a few clicks. But I don't think it's confusing.

Comment: @NickCraver: Were [you looking](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&hl=en&safe=off&q=meta+user+parent+link+stack+overflow+nick+craver+site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com&oq=meta+user+parent+link+stack+overflow+nick+craver+site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=44497l45958l0l46056l12l12l0l0l0l4l165l1123l3.8l11l0) for [that question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116237/add-links-between-users-so-and-mso-profile)?